# How to store values in an array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Say I have performed FFT on a set of data and i have the frequency and amplitude values.
I want to find the highest amplitude in each FFT block. The I need to find the frequency and amplitude of the points that are atleast greater than 0.4 times the max amplitude and save them in an array.. How can i do this??
I tried the following method by I keep getting an empty matrix....

```
% the code after FFT
peak_points = [];

    fmin = 60;
    fmax = 1000;
    region_of_interest = fmax>f & f>fmin;
    froi = f(region_of_interest);

    [p_max,loc] = max(seg_fft2(region_of_interest));

    p_max;
    fpeaks = froi(loc);

    [points, locatn] = findpeaks(seg_fft2(region_of_interest));

    if points > 0.4*p_max
        peak_points = [peak_points ; points locatn]
    end
```

Im bad with arrays.. So I cant seem to figure this out. Would appreciate someone's help in this... Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you intending to do the seg_ffr2 on the region of interest logical array or on froi?

or maybe points is vector and you should have:

```
aboveMax = points > 0.4*p_max;
if any(aboveMax)   
        peak_points = [peak_points ; points(aboveMax) locatn(aboveMax)]
end
```

Comment: Well I need to only consider the region between 60 Hz and 100 Hz and find the max in that region. 
The line `region_of_interest = fmax>f & f>fmin;` defines that region, so seg_fft2 is done on that...

Comment: Thank you. It works fine in detecting the correct amplitudes. However `locatn(aboveMax)` doesn't give me the frequency of the point. What can I do to get the frequency value??